# infinite While loop without statement

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, embedded

What it does mean? I saw below part of a code in embedded c program.I know this is a infinite loop, but for what purpose this part of a code is using in embedded c.

```
while(1)
{       
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: To keep running a piece of code untill some other condition has been met.

Comment: To keep the process as busy and  wait for something.

Comment: You mean the thread should wait for the condition `1` to turn into a `0`? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: To wait unitl an external event occurs

Comment: There are lots of condition like you want to keep your main thread alive always....

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman yes, it is not supposed to make any sense. You've got it wrong. _some other condition_ is not the condition used in `while()` loop.

Comment: note: infinite loops with no observable behaviour cause undefined behaviour in Standard C; although compiler vendors are generally sensible in this case where the programmer clearly intends to spin the thread

Comment: Other than the one from rabi shaw, the comments above are uninformed and generally wrong. The code will clearly run regardless of any condition being met, and isn't waiting for anything. And the host of an embedded application may have no operating system, no "sleep", and no resources to be consumed other than the power to run the CPU. The loop should be understood in terms of *interrupts* that do all the work. Edit: Matt's comment came after I wrote this. It's true that the behavior is undefined by the C standard, but that doesn't mean that it isn't defined by the implementation.

Comment: Edit 2: harper's answer goes beyond my comment, which omits his point 1 ... there may simply be nothing left to do until a reset, but halting the device is undesirable or not possible.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman What resources do you eat up on the embedded system, more precisely? This question isn't about PC programming.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Yes I have. On a PC. It doesn't apply here. Note the embedded tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This construct is used for two different purposes.

1. When you detect an error condition or the termination of your task you have to put the micro-controller in a definit state. The `while(1) { }` construct stalls further execution until the (watchdog) reset restarts the micro-controller.
    As *krambo* mentions in his comment this can be used to attach a JTAG debugger to examine the state of the micro-controller, variables, registers, and so on.
2. You can implement all the logic in interrupt handler. The main function performs the initialization and goes sleeping. While the main function can "sleep" the CPU can't. It just loops forever. Some micro-controller supports low-energy modes. This would be an alternative.

Comment: I have used empty while(1){} statements in debug builds to hold the CPU at the point where an error was detected.  This is just like the first purpose you described except instead of waiting for a watchdog reset, it's waiting for the debugger to be attached.  Then with the debugger I can halt the CPU and examine variables, the stack, etc. and get some clues as to how the error condition occurred.

Comment: Additionally: 3. This is the idle loop of an RTOS scheduler, and work is performed in separate thread contexts.

Comment: @kkrambo The processor can wait for a reset, watchdog, power fail, brown out, or watever reset source it may support. But it is an INFINITE wait in the context of your program. Your question does not mention that you have a JTAG debugger, what allows you to do what ever you want while the processor is still waiting.

Answer (score 2):

All embedded systems need an endless loop, because they must continue to execute for as long as the power is on. It doesn't make any sense for an embedded program to just execute and then return, as that would leave the processor dead and idle. This is likely the sole purpose of that loop.

I would guess your code comes from a bare metal microcontroller application, so you can safely disregard all PC programmer comments about sleeping and multi-threading; for a microcontroller application it doesn't make any sense not to consume 100% of the CPU, since nobody else is using it but you.

If you sleep on an embedded system you put the actual microcontroller hardware to sleep, if it supports it. You do so to save power, not to save CPU cycles.

Comment: Are you saying that "particular part of the code is for sleep purpose"?

Comment: @user25770 We can tell you that the code currently in you question is for endless looping. The purpose can't be deduced without addtional code lines around this loop.

Comment: @user25770 No, I'm saying that the people who babble about effective waiting, sleeping, multi-threading and context switches are talking nonsense from an embedded system point-of-view.

Comment: There are plenty of embedded systems where multi-threading is used - so such concerns are not entirely irrelevant.  In an RTOS environment the idle loop would normally be implemented thus, while other tasks doing that will starve lower priority tasks and prevent the idle loop (where power saving features may be used) from running.

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems, like uC/OS, require an idle task to run when no other task is running.  This would be at the lowest priority and would be preempted by a timer (scheduler) tick if it ever got a chance to run.  The case you describe could be such a task.